# Free SSL for Facebook

Tags: facebook, ssh, securesocial

It sounds like duplicate but i think it isn't. As you know Facebook wants secure https url while registering your application to developer page. I am a newbie developer and i don't want pay to SSL certificates. There were some sites which makes it freely
 *(social-server.com, phpfogapp.com, fbssl.co)*
. However none of them are working now. Is there any free way of getting secure url.

Answer (score 2):

You could try hosting your application in a free hosting like Heroku that is SSL powered - http://www.heroku.com/

Comment: heroku is extremely slow, but for newbies and for testing it´s perfect. you can even create a heroku space for yourself right when you create an app in the developer settings of facebook. it also comes with some code for testing. just keep in mind that heroku works with git, so you have to learn that too...a bit at least.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need SSL in dev mode.  I use SecureSocial with Facebook in HTTP only.